# What is the difference between focus and focus_set methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, focus

In the [effbot.org](http://effbot.org) website, there's a section talking about the [*Basic Widget Methods*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm). Two of these methods are `focus` and `focus_set`.

Believe or not, the following is what we find as reference under the [`focus`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus-method) method:

> The focus method.

Whereas the one talking about the [`focus_set`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_set-method) method says:

> Moves the keyboard focus to this widget. This means that all keyboard
>   events sent to the application will be routed to this widget.

My question is: do these two methods do the same thing? If not, what does `focus` do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the two are the same thing.  To be precise, `focus` is an alias for `focus_set`.  You can see this from a quick test in the interpreter:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.Text.focus is tkinter.Text.focus_set # Same function object
True
>>>
>>> help(tkinter.Text.focus)
Help on function focus_set in module tkinter:

focus_set(self)
    Direct input focus to this widget.

    If the application currently does not have the focus
    this widget will get the focus if the application gets
    the focus through the window manager.

>>>
```

Notice how calling `help()` on `focus` pulls up the documentation for `focus_set`.

Comment: Ok. Why are there aliases for tkinter methods? This is not the first time I found a situation like this...

Comment: I think only the Tkinter devs could answer that one. ;)  The Tkinter library always did seem a little bloated.  If I had to guess, it is either 1) to be like other GUI toolkits so that the learning curve is smaller or 2) to be extra convenient (if you can think of it, Tkinter has it).

Comment: @Rinzler my guess is that `focus_set` is derived from the tcl command and `focus` is the 'friendlier, more pythonic,' version.  I do not know which was added first.  I agree that duplication is somewhat annoying, but deprecation and removal is not easy.

Comment: @Rinzler - The Python [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/idle.html) IDE which ships with every installation of Python is written purely in Python and Tkinter.  You can find the source code in the standard library under `Lib/idlelib`.

Comment: @iCodez Yes, I know, but it is quite complicated to follow, there are a lot of files... Do you know others?

Comment: @Rinzler - Not really.  I haven't done much with Tkinter for a while (besides answering questions here).  I did manage to find some example code pieces [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ExampleCode).  Really though, the best way to learn something is to code with it.  Try thinking of applications that would be cool/useful and then go write them.  Maybe even share them with people so you get some real user feedback.  Tkinter is a great library, so it won't be long before you have it mastered. :)

Comment: I just tried the `is` comparison, which is now (py 3.9) `False` (`id(...)` also differ), however `==` on the methods compares to `True` (false vs. other methods), so I believe the claims that these methods are the "same" thing. *both* methods' reprs say the same thing: `<bound method Misc.focus_set...` so that's another indication.